# The maximum X and Y length / lengths

Tags: grammatical-number, ambiguity

One of the sections in the technical manual I am working on describes the maximum length of filenames and paths. According to the document, the maximum length of filenames is 31 character and the maximum length of paths is 255 characters.

I am trying to decide which heading would be the best.

- **The maximum filename and path length** - It is very easy to mistakenly assume that there is only a single one maximum length for both filenames and paths.
- **The maximum filename and path lengths** - It is possible to mistakenly assume that there are multiple maximum lengths for filenames and multiple maximum length for paths.
- **The maximum length of filenames and the maximum length of paths** - Clear but cumbersome.

Comment: Maximum length of filenames and paths. Are these limits still in effect?

Comment: You've got to compromise, and accuracy/clarity always trumps aesthetics.

Comment: @Xanne Windows still limits us to 255 characters. The 31 character limit is related to macOS. I do not have a Mac (they are very expensive in the country where I live), but some people on Internet say some Mac programs still do not support longer filenames. Anyway, it is usuall best to be on the safe side, because of legacy software. And some Windows programs that I use do not support spaces either.

Comment: "File and path name limits" as a heading, then go into the detail, where you can clearly distinguish as "maximum filename length" and "maximum path lengths", and you could make it clear that the second *includes* the first (if true).

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, I like this recommendation.

Comment: This is a great place to use the _limits of file names_ phraseology. There's no reason to use the conjoined _filenames and paths_ anywhere except in the title, where its ambiguity is a feature, not a bug -- it'll cause people to check and see what it means, and **that's** where you need to be crystal-clear.